# Css module in React component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-modules, react-css-modules

Having this css module:

**mymodule.module.css:**

```
ol li:not(:last-child)::after {
  color: red;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

React component:

```
import myStyles from './mymodule.module.css';
...

export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> = ({...} => {
   
   ...

   return (
            <li className={myStyles}>
             ...
            </li>
   );
```

There is a red line under className word which when hover states:

> Type '{ readonly [key: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'string'.ts(2322) index.d.ts(1749, 9): The expected type comes from
> property 'className' which is declared here on type
> 'DetailedHTMLProps<LiHTMLAttributes, HTMLLIElement>'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Css can be imported like `import  './mymodule.module.css';` and then you can use class name from the CSS in `className` prop.

Comment: In your CSS you don’t have any _class_. Since you style the elements, without classes, maybe you don’t need to use the `className` property at all.

Comment: try `<li className={myStyles.['my-class']}>`. Provide us with `myStyles` console.log

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file:

```css
# Add your default tag styles
ol li:not(:last-child)::after {
  color: red;
  margin: 1px;
}

# Add your class
.my-class {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

Your TSX

```
// import your stylesheet
import './mymodule.module.css';
...

export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps> =
 ({...}) => {
  ...
  // use the class as you would in HTML
  return (
   <li className="my-class">
    ...
   </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: you added `my-class` but not the styling for `ol` and `li`, in this case wouldn't they be applied globally to all ordered lists and list items from the project?

Comment: I want to find a way to apply those styles only in that class

Comment: `li` style will be automatically applied as soon as you import the CSS, no need of the class. If you remove `className="my-class"` it will use only whatever specified in the CSS as default style.

Comment: Your style will only be applied in tags that are like this `<ol><li>...`, so import this CSS where you `ol` element is, and you don't have to do anything... no need to use `className`

Answer (score 0):

Class Name property is for assigning specific class defined in your css file if you want to apply css on li tag, you just need to import css file in ts file or if you want to give it a styling with class name, you should give its a parent a class like this:

**React component:**

```
<ol className={myStyles.abc}
  <li>
    ...
  </li>
</ol>
```

**mymodule.module.css:**

```
.abc li:not(:last-child)::after {
  color: red;
  margin: 1px;
}
```